# I need to get rid of the timestamp on excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So currently I am extracting from info from SQL and the date is coming as "5/1/2016 12:12:05 AM" and I just need the date! I already tried to change the format in excel but it only changes the view and when I click on the cell it still the same. I am trying to use VBA now to see if there is any code that can solve this problem. I have the following code but I get an error saying "type mismatch" on .value = datevalue....  Here is what I currently have:

```
Sub timechange()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
    With Range("b5:b3000")
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
        .Value = datevalue(.Value)
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000194/difference-between-date-and-time-w-out-work-week-excel/38001028#38001028 There is only `datetime` in Excel you cannot store a date without time or a time without date in an Excel cell.

Comment: Tip, the date is the integer, and the time is the decimal.  You may also need to convert your date from a string to an excel date.

Comment: You're getting the data from an SQL Server. The easiest way is to change the T-SQL statement to retrieve the data and get only the date part of the `datetime`. SQL knows the difference since 2008 and you can get the date only. Also, a DB server will always handle such things much faster than any Excel solution we can think of here. So, you might want to tackle it from a different angle. Alternatively, just strip away the time with `ROUNDDOWN` or `CLng`.

Comment: Changing the format does only change what is displayed.  It does NOT change what is stored.  To remove the time, return the Integer portion to the cell.  But you'll need to do that one at a time, else you will get the type mismatch error on `.Value = datevalue(.Value)`.  Hint -- your loop isreferencing the same range `2 to LR` times, which makes no sense.  It is okay for setting the `.numberformat` property. but will fail with the error on the `.Value` property