# VBA Script to Loop Through Specific Date Range

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Good evening StackOverflow cohort,

After an interesting baptism by fire in learning VBA, I have a more advanced question regarding executing my script in a loop. Currently, I have the script referencing a cell in a specific worksheet, which houses the current date. The script places this date into a variable portion of a URL string, which then executes data retrieval from this webpage.

My goal is to include DATEDIF somewhere within this to signify how many days are missing between the last available data pulled and today's date. If possible, the script would then be able to adjust the variable URL string accordingly to replace each date through this loop, then add the data in the sheet below the previous pulled data. This is my script so far below:

```
Sub MasterDataIngest()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook

With wkb

Set sh1 = Worksheets("SheetOne")
Set wkb = Workbooks("SheetTwo")
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

sh1.Activate

    IE.Visible = False

    IE.navigate "http://website.com/dir1/dir2/" & Format(Cells(1, 1).Value, "yyyymmdd") & "/file.txt"

    'Check for good connection to web page loop!

        Do
        If IE.readyState = 4 Then
        IE.Visible = False
        Exit Do
        Else
        DoEvents
        End If
        Loop

    'Wait for window to open!
    Application.wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    IE.Visible = False


    IE.navigate "http://website.com/dir1/dir2/" & Format(Cells(1, 1).Value, "yyyymmdd") & "/file.txt"

            IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
            IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
            sh1.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False,    DisplayAsIcon:=False
            sh1.Range("A2").Select
                IE.Quit

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000194/difference-between-date-and-time-w-out-work-week-excel/38001028#38001028

Comment: First your `With wkb` should go below the line `Set wkb = ...`, but there isn't any use. If you are just to open those **txt** files without logons, Excel can open it directly and drop the IE component.

Comment: Hi Ralph, to make this even more interesting, the webpage I'm using does require a login, I think I can trick IE to only ask for the login once, which would prevent the VBA from asking for a password for each webpage I cycled through

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `DateDiff`.

If you call DateDiff like this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim a as Long
Dim b as Date
Dim c as Date

b = CDate(Cells(1,1).Value)
c = CDate(Cells(1,2).Value)
a = Abs(DateDiff("d",b,c))

Debug.Print("The difference in days between b and c is " & a)

End Sub
```

This will give you the number of days between two supplied dates. With this you can easily check how long its been since you last checked if you compare the last date you have with the current date (You can use `Now()` for this)

You can read more about how to use the [`DateDiff`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php) function on that tutorial, too.