# Date format in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code which pull the details from .msg file (outlook files) and update in excel sheet. While reflecting the date column, it is showing as "3/9/2016  11:03:27 AM" but I want to show only date and not time.

I used the format option i.e.

```
Sheet2.Cells(Row + 1, 23) = VBA.Format(sentDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

but it is showing the date a "8/3/2016  00:00". I want to reflecting only date and nothing else. Please guide me as to what all changes required to reflect only date.

Comment: Your code effectively rounds the date/time data down, but does not have any effect on the **display format**. Try this: `Sheet2.Cells(Row + 1, 23).NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"`

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sheet2.Cells(Row + 1, 23).Value = sentDate
Sheet2.Cells(Row + 1, 23).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy;@"
```

Yet, I have a feeling that the cell does not really contain a date but merely text. So, please also try to change the `.NumberFormat` to the following first:

```
Sheet2.Cells(Row + 1, 23).NumberFormat = "General"
```

If the dates are now showing all as numbers then these are actual dates and the first proposal should work. If not, then these are not dates yet and you'll have to convert the text (which looks like dates) to dates first.

For more information you might want to read this: [Difference between date and time w/out work week Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000194/difference-between-date-and-time-w-out-work-week-excel/38001028#38001028)