# How to copy cell based on current system date?

Tags: vba, excel

I attached my table in screenshot. Based on A column which contains date, I would like to select only one valued from B and C column from sheet1 and paste it to sheet2. 
The date must be a current system date. Help ME PLZ

[image]

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: Google excel date functions

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA solution or a Excel-formula-based solution?

Comment: @Ralph excel will be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite simple with an Excel-formula based approach:

[image]

Try the following formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TODAY(),A:A,0))
```

Of course, this formula can be on any other sheet and doesn't have to be on the same sheet as the above data values. Just make sure that the dates in column `A` are dates without time. For more information you might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38001028/1153513

### Update:

<sub>Elaborating upon answer based on additional question asked in comment.</sub>

If you are looking for a different date than `Today()` then you can *construct* it using the `Date()` function. This function works like this for October 30, 2017:

```
=Date(2017, 10, 30)
```

Together with the functions [Year](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YEAR-function-C64F017A-1354-490D-981F-578E8EC8D3B9), [Month](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579A2881-199B-48B2-AB90-DDBA0EBA86E8), and [Day](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DAY-function-8A7D1CBB-6C7D-4BA1-8AEA-25C134D03101) you can rewrite today's date as:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))
```

Like this you can dynamically adjust the date you are searching for based on today's date. So, if you are looking for the exact same date just one year earlier than this would be:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))
```

So, your *adjusted* formula as posted above for cell `E24` would be (searching for today's date one year in the past):

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),A:A,0))
```

Comment: your formula works. but i need one more help, how to calculate for the previous year 2016 with today date 30.10.2016

Comment: I already did it bro. But i am new here and low reputation score, its not working for me.

Comment: thank you very much bro. both the code works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Well now you didn't specify where on sheet2 you want the data be pasted so i just placed them in A1:A2

```
Sub test()
Dim lLastUsed As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
lLastUsed = Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

For i = 2 To lLastUsed
    If Replace(Date, "-", ".") = Range("A" & i).Value Then
        ws1.Range("B" & i & ":C" & i).Copy
    End If
Next i

ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: Would actually change to `lLastUsed = ws1.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and aslo in the if statement  `= ws1.Range("A" & i).Value Then
` by doing this you are sure the values come from the right WorkSheet