# Changing cells with date values to match current date, but keep original time

Tags: excel, vba, time

[image]

Afternoon all! Got a slight little query for you to ponder over.

I currently have 2 tables with the above times (which are dynamic and change often). The left table pulls data on times between 08:00 and 18:30, and the right pulls times between 18:30 and 4:30 the next day including the dates attached to those times. When i open my workbook, The times are updated on WorkBook_Open through VBA, I need to update the times shown so that the values keep the time, but update the date to the current day, so if the data pulled is 01/12/2023 12:30, then the cell updates to 04/12/2023 12:30.....

I use the formula

```
cel.Formula = "=TEXT(" & cel & ",""hh:mm"") + Today()"
```

which seems to work on all times that fall on the current day. However the issue that I'm facing, is, for example in the right hand table... the 00:15 values are for the next day, so the above formula runs through and converts it to the current day time... for EG:

01/01/1990 21:30
02/01/1990 00:15

But running the formula will change it to:

04/12/2023 21:30
04/12/23023 00:15

Whereas the rightmost value should be 05/12/23023 00:15

If any of that makes sense then any help would be appreciated, working with Times in Excel is definitely one of my weaker skills

Many Thanks :)

Comment: The answer on this link may help explain it:  [Difference between date and time w/out work week Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000194/difference-between-date-and-time-w-out-work-week-excel/38001028#38001028)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the date difference between today and `FIRST_CELL`
- Using a temp cell to store the date differnce in `Demo2`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo1()
    Dim c As Range, iOffset As Long
    Const FIRST_CELL = "A1"
    iOffset = Date - CDate(Format(Range(FIRST_CELL), "MM/dd/yyyy"))
    Debug.Print iOffset
    For Each c In Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        c.Value = c.Value + iOffset
    Next
End Sub

Sub Demo2()
    Dim c As Range, iOffset As Long
    Const FIRST_CELL = "A1"
    Const TEMP_CELL = "E1"
    Range(TEMP_CELL) = Date - CDate(Format(Range(FIRST_CELL), "MM/dd/yyyy"))
    Range(TEMP_CELL).Copy
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
    Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
    Range(TEMP_CELL).ClearContents
End Sub
```

[image]

---

If you change the date layout a little bit, updating will be eaiser.

- Apply formulas on column A and B
- `BaseDate` and `TimeOffset` can be moved any sheet in the workbook. You can apply `TimeOffset` in formulas. eg. A1 formula will be `=$E$1+0.53125`
- Changing `BaseDate` will automatically update all date in column A and B

[image]

Comment: Thank you super much for this. I was driving home from work and had a brainwave with the exact idea as this :) Many thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the starting date with `"=TEXT(" & cel & ",""hh:mm"")`.  That will take your date/time and extract just the time before adding todays date, which is why both dates are the same.

Just add todays date to your original date/time. `=A1+TODAY()`

[image]

---

Time in Excel is just a number (I know I've said this on another post somewhere, but can't find it at the moment).

The part before the decimal point is the day, and the part after the decimal is the time.  Todays date as a number is 45264.  Halfway through the day, or midday is 45264.5, 6PM is 45264.75, etc.

So, if you're times are entered just as times with no dates attached they're actually day 0:   `00/01/1900 18:00` or `0.75`

So if you want to change the date just remove the integer from the value and add a new one:

[image]

Comment: Hey Darren, thanks for the reply! Appreciate the effort you've made in your response. However the times that I'm using already have dates included, they just aren't shown. So they aren't 00/01/1900 :) so just adding todays date won't help! Also, as you can see in your third table, you're hitting the same issue i'm having, whereby 04:30 should be 05/12, and not 04/12, as the times are in chronological order :)